# MVVM Behavior ScrollView Error Loading

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my project, i have a behavior to detect when ScrollView is at bottom in my datagrid.

his works very well only when the data is loaded from the view loading and requiring a ScrollView directly .

Sometimes my data can be loaded in a second time and it does not.

My Behavior

```
public class ScrollViewerMonitor
{
    public static DependencyProperty AtEndCommandProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AtEndCommand", typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(ScrollViewerMonitor),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnAtEndCommandChanged));

    public static ICommand GetAtEndCommand(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(AtEndCommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAtEndCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AtEndCommandProperty, value);
    }


    public static void OnAtEndCommandChanged(
        DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)d;
        if (element != null)
        {
            element.Loaded -= element_Loaded;
            element.Loaded += element_Loaded;
        }
    }

    static void element_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        element.Loaded -= element_Loaded;
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(element);
        if (scrollViewer == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ScrollViewer.VerticalOffsetProperty, typeof(ScrollViewer));
        dpd.AddValueChanged(scrollViewer, delegate (object o, EventArgs args)
        {
            bool atBottom = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset
                           >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
            if (atBottom)
            {
                var atEnd = GetAtEndCommand(element);
                if (atEnd != null)
                {
                    atEnd.Execute(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    static T FindChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
    {
        var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
        queue.Enqueue(root);

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            DependencyObject current = queue.Dequeue();
            for (int i = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current) - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
                var typedChild = child as T;
                if (typedChild != null)
                {
                    return typedChild;
                }
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In my XAML

```
<D:DataGridTemplate  x:Name="Datagrid" Behavior:ScrollViewerMonitor.AtEndCommand="{Binding LoadCommand,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

I would like that even if the scrollview does not appear at startup, the behavior can detect when the scrollview appears

This Datagrid doesn't work:

```
            <D:DataGridTemplate  x:Name="Datagrid" Behavior:ScrollViewerMonitor.AtEndCommand="{Binding LoadCommand}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedID}" SelectedValuePath="Swmo_id" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"  ItemsSource= "{Binding TypeMouvement, Converter={StaticResource TypeCollectionConverter},Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
            <!--"{Binding TypeMouvement, Converter={StaticResource TypeCollectionConverter}}"TypeMouvement-->
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Helper:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <D:DataGridFirstColumn Visibility="{Binding Data.TypeMouvement, Converter={StaticResource FirstColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
                <!--Mofi_Id-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="N° Chrono" Width="Auto"  Binding="{Binding Path=Mofi_Id, Converter={StaticResource GestionMouvementConverter}, ConverterParameter=Mofi_Id}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                        <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource  ColumnTypeConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding  Path="Data.DataChampFinal[0].Cham_Order" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" />
                                <Binding  Path="Data.TypeMouvement" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" />
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <!--id-->

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"   Binding="{Binding Path=Swmo_id}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[1].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />

                <!--Visibility="{Binding Data.Swmo_id, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, ConverterParameter=1, Source={StaticResource proxy} "{Binding coucou, Converter={StaticResource DisplayIndexOrder}, ConverterParameter=0}" DisplayIndex="{Binding Int10, Mode = TwoWay, FallbackValue = 1}" Visibility="{Binding Data.TypeMouvement, Converter={StaticResource ColumnTypeConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"  />  -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date de validation"  Binding="{Binding Path=Mofi_Datefinal, Converter={StaticResource GestionMouvementConverter}, ConverterParameter=Mofi_Datefinal}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                        <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource  ColumnTypeConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding  Path="Data.DataChampFinal[2].Cham_Order" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" />
                                <Binding  Path="Data.TypeMouvement" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" />
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date du mouvement" Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Datemouv, Converter={StaticResource GestionMouvementConverter}, ConverterParameter=ConvertDateFR }"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[3].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date d'Entrée CM." Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Dateentreecm, Converter={StaticResource GestionMouvementConverter}, ConverterParameter=ConvertDateFR }"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[4].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Entrepôt Fiscal"   Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Identrepotfiscal}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[5].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" /> 
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Entrepôt Compte"   Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Identrcpt}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[6].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Compte"  Binding="{Binding Path=Comp_Id}"  
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[7].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Couleur" Binding="{Binding Path=Comp_Idcouleur}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[8].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sous Compte"    Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Idsouscompte}"  
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[9].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type mouvement" Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Mouvement}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[10].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type justificatif si ecrit auto." Width="Auto"  Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Idtypeecrit}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[11].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code Produit"   Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Id}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[12].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Degré"  Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Degré}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[13].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code Mouvement"   Binding="{Binding Path=Como_Id}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[14].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Entrée/sortie"   Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_TypeMvt}"  
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[15].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sens"   Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Sens}"  
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[16].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type de Tiers du Mvt."     Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Idtierstyp}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[17].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code du Tiers" Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Codetiers}"  
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[18].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Désignation du Tiers"      Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Nomtiers}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[19].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type de Pièce Gestion"     Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Idpiecegest}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[20].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Référence Pièce Origine1"  Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Refpiece1}"  
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[21].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                ...
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="CRA" Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Cra}"  
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[26].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type Nature Expédition"    Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Idexptype}"  
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[27].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qte. régie en L."          Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Qteregielitre}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[28].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vol. effectif en L."       Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Effectiflitre}"  
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[29].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qte. Gest. Commerciale en U." Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Qtegestcom}"  
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[30].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Libre5"  Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Libre5}"    
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[40].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Libre6"  Binding="{Binding Path=Mobr_Libre6}"    
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.DataChampFinal[41].Cham_Order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibleColumnConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />

            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Historique..." Command="{Binding GoSeeHistory}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </D:DataGridTemplate>
```

And this One is Fine:

```
       <D:DataGridTemplate  x:Name="Datagrid" 
                         Behavior:ScrollViewerMonitor.AtEndCommand="{Binding LoadCommand}"  
                         TablePaged:SortColumn.AtSortingColumnCommand="{Binding SortingColumnCommand}" 
                         Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding DataProduits,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Helper:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Currentcollection" Source="{Binding Path= ColumnName}" />

        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Id}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Id" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Désignation" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Des}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Des" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Désignation court" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Lib}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Lib" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Millésime" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Millesime}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Millesime" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Type}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Type" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Centilisation" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_centilisation}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_centilisation" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Appellation" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_IdAppel}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_IdAppel" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Produit de base" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Idpdb}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Idpdb" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Couleur" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Idcouleur}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Idcouleur" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ref. Douane" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Idrefdouane}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Idrefdouane" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Catégorie" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Idcategorie}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Idcategorie" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Regie" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Idprodregie}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Idprodregie" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Statut regie" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Idsteap}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Idsteap" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ste. d'appartenance" Binding="{Binding Path=Prod_Cloture}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                    <Binding Path="Data.ColumnName" ConverterParameter="Prod_Cloture" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Source="{StaticResource proxy}" >
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:VisibilityColumn CurrentCollection="{StaticResource Currentcollection}"  />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                 </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            </DataGridTextColumn>


        </DataGrid.Columns>


    </D:DataGridTemplate>
```

Comment: Strange, in Loaded event you should always be able to acces the scrollviewer, even if its hidden.

Comment: The code you've shown appears to work as expected. Notice that `,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is not needed in a command binding... is it missing somewhere else? I'm afraid you should share more of your xaml and maybe also the LoadCommand of the VM, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: the problem is in FindChildOfType. In the While, it dosn't find the scrollView. and execution is only on the view loading.

Comment: That's why I've asked if you could post more of your xaml. I've tried with a simple datagrid and it works. I'm unsure how to reproduce your GUI how to compile your DataGridTemplate, sorry

Comment: I just tested with a simple datagrid without style and without usercontrol and it's the same thing , I post a datagrid that works and one that does not work

Comment: @CamilleColvray Can I replace your `D:DataGridTemplate` with `DataGrid` in order to compile my xaml? Do you agree/confirm that I can use only one simple column instead of many and I can simply specify `local:ScrollViewerMonitor.AtEndCommand="{Binding TestCommand}"` to test the behaviour? I'm trying to get a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, which is the relevant difference between the 2 xaml: maybe the `SelectedValue` binding ?

Comment: i tried with only one column and without selectedvalue but same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115383/discussion-between-camille-colvray-and-machine-learning).